# building beginner_tutorials returns "No Makefile in package" errors

Tags: ros-fuerte, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new in the world of ROS and have just installed ROS (Fuerte). I'm trying to make my way through the tutorial steps, but I'm encountering some problems. When I execute 'rosmake beginner_tutorials' in step 4 (1.2.1. Using rosmake) I get the following messages:

```
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> beginner_tutorials [ make ]
```

The building process completes quickly and reports 0 failures.

The above messages and the short building time are not what I expected based on the tutorial information.

What is going wrong here ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32747/building-beginner_tutorials-returns-%22no-makefile-in-package%22-errors/) by [Need More Input](https://answers.ros.org/users/2260/need-more-input/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see anything wrong in the information you provided.

Those are not errors.

When building core packages that were installed from binaries, the `ROS_NOBUILD` file tells `rosmake` it is not necessary to compile anything there.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1